# Which statistics can I form from 22 binary comparisons between experiment and theory?

Tags: prediction

I have a limited set of experimental data against which I can compare my theoretical results. The experimental set consists of 22 binary data points (-1/+1). What kind of statistics can I use to characterize my predictions?

So far, I have the correctly predicted: 15/22.

Which other statistics are meaningful? Can I claim that based on this "training" data, new predictions will be correct at the same rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple chi-square test for each of the 22 comparison tables should work nicely. If the tests are not independent, then you might want to add a family-wise correction factor such as the Bonferroni to adjust the significance levels. This would be a test of independence or unrelatedness between your observed vs the theoretical results. Good discussions of this can be found in many statistics books. My particular favorite is Thomas Wickens' book * Multiway Contingency Tables Analysis for the Social Sciences*...chapter 2 is devoted to 2-way tables.

Comment: Ok, to elaborate a bit: I could use the chi-square test on a contingency table of true positive, true negative, false positive and false negative rates to check if the difference between my theoretical model and the experimental results differ by chance, or if there is a true difference not described in my theory? So, as the developer of the theory, I probably would hope for *no* significant difference between theory and experiment. Would this approach make sense?

Comment: Correct. Confirming the null hypothesis of no significant difference between observed and theoretical information is the desired outcome, in this instance.